# Displaying the value in a Laravel Nova Value metric

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I need to show the sum of the `price` column of model `Foo`. Right now I can do it with this.

```
    public function calculate(Request $request)
    {

        return $this
            ->sum($request, Contribution::class, 'contribution_amount')
            ->dollars();
    }
```

Which show the following output.

- For sum of `22` => `$22`
- For sum of `3120` => `$3.10k`

I need to just show `$22`, `$3120` without any formatting. I tried to override the aggregate function but it still doesn't give me the correct output format.

```
protected function aggregate($request, $model, $function, $column = null, $dateColumn = null)
    {
        $query = $model instanceof Builder ? $model : (new $model)->newQuery();

        $column = $column ?? $query->getModel()->getQualifiedKeyName();

        $previousValue = with(clone $query)->whereBetween(
            $dateColumn ?? $query->getModel()->getCreatedAtColumn(), $this->previousRange($request->range)
        )->{$function}($column);

        return $this->result(
            with(clone $query)->whereBetween(
                $dateColumn ?? $query->getModel()->getCreatedAtColumn(), $this->currentRange($request->range)
            )->{$function}($column)
        )->previous($previousValue);
    }
```

Can anyone give a pointer here?

Comment: What happens if you don't chain the `dollars()` at the end?

Comment: I've tried that. No luck. It's 3.20k

Comment: Weird. Could you show us your Contribution model? Is there any accessors defined on contribution_amount?

Comment: None. It just extends the Eloquent model. No extra code. Not even a cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future readers..

As of Nova `1.3.1` we can use `Numeral.js` formatting to format the values in the `Trend/Value` metric.

```
return $this
            ->result($val)
            ->dollars()
            ->format('0,0.00')
```

Above snippet will format the value to be displayed to two decimal places.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for detailing this.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.2.0

The format happens in `nova/resources/js/components/Metrics/Base/ValueMetric.vue`

```
formattedValue() {
    if (!this.isNullValue) {
        const numeralValue = numeral(this.value)

        return numeralValue.value() > 1000
            ? this.prefix + numeralValue.format('(0.00a)')
            : this.prefix + this.value
    }

    return ''
},
```

It is not configurable.

**Workaround**

You can edit above mentioned file just to return non format value. Then run `npm run prod` to build & run `php artisan nova:publish` command to copy updated files.

**Note** - Your changes will get override when you update Nova version in future.